# how do I get a View from a ViewGroup in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm still quite new to Android. I would like to access a TextEdit view in a ListView I've created. Each ListView item contains a Linear Layout, which in turn contains an EditText.

I'm trying to do this and it doesn't work.

```
View v = MyListView.getChildAt(2);
EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext_1);
```

where edittext_1 is in the xml that defines each LinearLayout item in the ListView.

EDIT: More code for reference. This is called in my activity's fragment to create the ListView.

```
Resources res = getResources();
            GradeTypeListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gtListView);

//          Applies the adapter to populate the ListView
            gtAdapter = new GradeTypeListAdapter(this.getActivity(), gradeTypeList, res, this);
            GradeTypeListView.setAdapter(gtAdapter);
```

My adapter inflates each ListView item using a LinearLayout template. The getView() code from the adapter is

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        //  If the view doesn't yet exist, assign views in templates to views in holder.
        if(convertView == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course_list_item, null);


            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.comment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            holder.letterGrade = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.letterGrade);
            holder.percentage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.percentage);

            v.setTag(holder);

        //  If the view exists, then holder equals the object returned by getTag(). getTag is a method
        //  that allows a view to basically hold an object.
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        if(data.size() <= 0 ) {
            holder.title.setText("No Data");
            System.out.println("Empty I guess");

        //  Set the views' contents and onClickListener
        } else {
            course = null;
            course = (CourseWithGrade) data.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(course.getTitle());
            holder.comment.setText("Hard-coded comment!");
            holder.letterGrade.setText(course.letterGrade);
            holder.percentage.setText(course.percentage);

            v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        }
        return v;
    }
```

R.layout.course_list_item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxWidth="110dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/letterGrade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/percentage"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:maxWidth="110dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/percentage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your problem? NullPointerException?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Yes, it's a NPE at the 2nd line above. I'm not sure why.

Comment: R.id.edittext_1 is inside the layout of the row?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I've added more code above. R.id.edittext_1 is in grade_type_list_item.xml which defines a LinearLayout I populate using a custom adapter. Maybe the ListView doesn't know about R.id.edittext_1 because it's behind the adapter? btw, edittext_1 is not actually in my code. I was trying to be theoretical. Being able to access any text from a ListView is my goal.

Comment: R.layout.course_list_item xml?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I've added the XML.

Comment: You should use v.findViewById with an ID which is inside this XML.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I am using v.findViewById with an ID inside the correct XML. However, I've realized that `myListView.getChildCount()` returns 0. But my code doesn't crash when assigning `v = myListView.getChildAt(2);`  It instead crashes at `v.findViewById`. Since my ListView is populating, why am I getting a childCount of 0 and why isn't `getChildAt(2)` not crashing?